# Validation of a new block

Tags: mining-theory, bitcoin-core-development

A new block is added to blockchain if more than 50% of miners say that it is solved correctly. Does it mean that all other miners also do the same proof of work by including the same transactions as in the broadcasted block, and same nounce, as used by the miner of latest block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each full-node checks the validity of blocks. Checking the validity of a block is indeed done by repeating all steps of building that block and checking for adherence to all consensus rules. If a block infringes any rule, a full-node will consider the block invalid, ignore the block, and ban the node that sent it to him from his peers for 24h for sending invalid information.

As each miner should be running a full-node to stay abreast of the current blockchain-tip, either all miners or no miners should consider a block valid (as long as they are in agreement on the consensus rules that apply).

Comment: Just want to confirm one thing, I suppose the block validation is done after the block was mined by a miner, but once the block is rejected by the maximum full nodes, then the blockchain with that block leading is ignored and a new valid block is mined by another full node, and then the valid block will lead the blockchain, until another block is added above it.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, but every node _independently_ checks validity of blocks and ignores invalid blocks, invalid blocks don't get created usually.  If they do get created  they don't get seen by most of the network, as they don't get relayed.

Answer (score 0):

> A new block is added to blockchain if more than 50% of miners say that
>   it is solved correctly.

wrong. you can not caclulate the percentage. you can either accept block to your chain or reject it

Comment: If other nodes / miners in the network simply accept or reject it, then there is suppose to be a threshold whether in number or in percentage that decides, whether block is to be added to chain or rejected.

Comment: you can not caclulate the percentage. you can either accept block to your chain or reject it